# macOS NSProgressIndicator stops animation when I export my project as .app file

Tags: macos, nsprogressindicator

I have a strange bug. I add a NSProgressIndicator in my .xib file. I am building a macOS Project. When I run the project in my Xcode, the NSProgressIndicator works fine. But when I export the MacTestDemo1.app under the Products, and run it (both on my own computer and on others'),the NSProgressIndicator doesn't work But everything else works fine. I don't know why.

I write a sample test project and find that when the viewcontroller is presented by presentViewControllerAsModalWindow, the spinner doesn't work. But if put it on the original window, it works well, too. Really a strange bug! Does anyone know why?
Need help from your guys. Thanks very much in advance.
[I export MacTestDemo1.app here out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3rYe.png)

Comment: Oh, I find the reason. My spinner indicator is added on a viewcontroller that showes by presentViewControllerAsModalWindow. So it doesn't working on the modalWidow. It does working on the original window. Don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For there is no answer, I come to answer my own question. I still don't know why it happens. But I find an alternative solution.

I use CAShapeLayer class to draw my own customized loading spinner in a another thread and it did work when i exported it out as .app.

Hope this helps you if someone has meet the same problem as mine.